# Liferay - Layout for each pages

Tags: liferay

In Liferay, can we apply layout template for each page at runtime?

Regards
Vishal G

Answer (score 3):

*Liferay 5.2*: Yes, you can. From the user popup menu click **Manage Pages**, select your desired page from the website tree and click the **Look and Feel** tab.

Note: There are two sets of tabs with Look and Feel. One for the site (higher tabset) and one for a single page (lower tabset).

Comment: Hi AOI,

Thanks for your quick reply. Will that be possible programatically?

Regards
Vishal G

Comment: Yes, however it requires advanced knowledge of Liferay framework and considerable effort. You need to setup a development environment for *ext*.

*ext* is a top-level layer of Liferay that lets you customize the whole framework programatically to suit your needs. You can read more about it at Liferay.com's forums.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an ext.  You can deploy a liferay hook plugin that runs your own custom ServicePreAction which grabs the layout template and sets it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The Look and feel modal popup is useful, but there is maybe a better way to do that.

Create every layout as needed (see [this article](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout+Template))

Then add those two lines in your theme in init_custom.vm or portal_normal.vm (at the top)

```
#set ($layout_id = $typeSettingsProperties.getProperty("layout-template-id"))
#set ($css_class = $css_class + " layout_$layout_id")
```

This add a specific css class on your body tag.
So you can set different style on each custom layout page.

ie (if your layout id is "your_custom_layout") :

```
body.layout_your_custom_layout #column-1 { background: #eee; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```