# Liferay 6 - How to set up custom layout as default?

Tags: templates, layout, default, liferay-6

I'm working on a Liferay 6 project, and part of the project is to create a new layout template to be used for the entire site as the default. Liferay's own wiki is very sparse on documentation about layout templates, and I haven't had better luck with Google searches or even here on SO.

I did find one article ( [Liferay - Layout for each pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093456/liferay-layout-for-each-pages) ) that sort of answers the question, but it seems like it might be overkill. In that question, the goal was to change the template based on the page, so the answer was to create a Hook and use that to set the template on the fly as needed. Here, I just want to have this custom template be the default for *all* pages, all the time, which is why I think the answer to that other question might be more than is really needed.

If anyone has the answer to this puzzler, please let me know. Thanks!

-- JLM --

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I've figured out my confusion. Liferay has two types of layout templates -- templates that are part of a **theme**, which is one type of Liferay project, as well as actual layout template projects themselves.

- The templates in a theme are where you set up the overall page layout for the site. The main page template, named portal_normal.vm, is a full web page with an <html> tag, a <head> and <body>, etc. Other templates in the theme are usually page fragments.
- A Layout Template, on the other hand, is **only** for laying out the portlets in the main content region of your page (which is defined by tags in your Theme's template files). It is **always** a fragment and can only have <div> elements or a <table> for laying out the portlets.

Fortunately, this actually makes answering my question very easy, at least in the context that I needed. Per Liferay's documentation at http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+To+Change+Liferay+Default+Theme :

> Note: As of 6.x, you cannot just use the theme id specified in the liferay-look-and-feel.xml. Instead, go to Control Panel->Plugins Configuration->Click on theme of interest->note the Plugin ID and use that [as the value for default.theme.id in portal-ext.properties]

I hope this helps some other people trying to figure this out!

Comment: Yeah Liferay can be confusing, and I find the documentation at times really frustrating.

Comment: The documentation is frustrating as it is usually out of date. I find just looking at the source to be the fastest route to resolve an issue.